# Call a method when back button pressed

Tags: android, database, list, refresh

I have a list in my app. In another activity, user deletes a row from database and it returns to the main activity (I use finish() here). When it returns back, the row that has been removed from database is still on the list. If user presses refresh button, it disappears.
How can I refresh it automatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override your original Activity's (the one that is showed when the user presses back) `onResume()`, so it looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  refreshListMethod();
  super.onResume();
}
```

`refreshListMethod();` is whatever approach you chose to refresh the List since you say:

> user presses refresh button, it disappears.

So turn that approach into a method so you can use it wherever needed.

Comment: You're super! :) Thank you!

Comment: Is this a lot better than my method, @A--C? I have done it both ways in different activities but wasn't sure if there was a "best practice". When I refresh I normally re-create the activity anyway, except with a list you can use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Just wondering if I need to rethink how I do things

Comment: I would say `onResume()` is the better practice; it's definitely cleaner. And so, it should be faster and it adheres to the Activity lifecycle conventions. When you want to change the UI of an Activity, you don't recreate it, you keep using the Activity.

Comment: That makes sense, I was thinking you would need to recreate to refresh the UI but I guess you wouldn't need to recreate variables and things like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the `Activity` When you click a list item, you can call `finish()` on the `ListActivity` then recreate the `Activity` with an `Intent` after you delete the row in the new `Activity`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, firstly. I've tried it, but I thought it makes the app lubber, a little bit. A---C's answer is the clearest and the easiest way I think. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it working. I usually do it this way but maybe it does make it slower. I wasn't sure if there would be much of a difference but maybe I was wrong